# Groupby an array and get elements as subarray using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like below and need to transform this array with sub arrays

[{
author: " "
category: "test1"
date: "8 September 2020"
extension: null
id: 5
maintitle: "test"
siteName: "site1"
title: "test1"
url: ""
},

{
author: ""
category: "test1"
date: "10 September 2020"
extension: null
id: 4
maintitle: "test2"
siteName: "site1"
title: "test2"
url: ""
},

{
author: " "
category: "test3"
date: "2 September 2020"
extension: null
id: 1
maintitle: "test3"
siteName: "Site3"
title: "test3"
url: ""
}]

The output would look like this:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    date: "8 September 2020",
    title: test1,
    category: test1,
    "files": {
      "Site1": [{
          author: " "
          date: "8 September 2020",
          extension: null,
          title: "test1"
        }, {
          author: " ",
          date: "10 September 2020"
          extension: null,
          title: "test2"
          url: ""
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  [{
      id: 2,
      date: "8 September 2020",
      title: "test3",
      category: "test3",
      "files": {
        "site3": [{
          author: " ",
          date: "30 August 2020",
          extension: null,
          title: "test3",
          url: ""
        }]
      }]
      }]
```

Groupby need to do with sitename and Category using Jquery/javascript. Please help me on this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: an object can not be a key.

Comment: @NinaScholz can u please explain more

Comment: **Forms,....Policies**  these are wrong. You need to have a key and a value like in the rest......

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array for the wanted groups and an iterative approach for the nested arrays.

```js
const
    data = [{ author: "Merin", category: "Forms", date: "8 September 2020", documentName: "Credit1 Forms", documentUrl: "", id: 5, siteName: "Credit", title: "Forms" }, { author: "Sandeep", category: "Forms", date: "10 September 2020", documentName: "AFAD1 Forms", documentUrl: "#", id: 4, siteName: "Credit", title: "Forms" }, { author: "Jithin", category: "Policies", date: "2 September 2020", documentName: "Credit1 Manuel", documentUrl: "#", id: 1, siteName: "Credit", title: "Policies" }],
    groups = [['category', 'files'], ['siteName']],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        groups
            .reduce((p, [key, children = o[key]], i) => {
                let value, group;
                ({ [key]: value, ...o } = o);
                group = p.find(g => g[key] === value);
                if (!group) p.push(group = { ...(i === 0 ? { id: p.length + 1 } : {}), [key]: value, [children]: [] });
                return group[children];
            }, r)
            .push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz,Thanks for helping me. I would like to get array like below image. can you help me to acheive same

Comment: added in question itself @Nina Scholz

Comment: Any suggestions, plz

Comment: Thank you @Nina Scholz. One more update also. Can I have some more questions.Added one more image in question.

Comment: for the latest request, i would take tow nested custom loops without using an abstraction, like the above code. so. if youwant it, go ahead and try this. maybe in a new question. btw, does this answer answers your original question?

Comment: question edited here itself. the other post removed by someone else.Please help me. I am tried so many things and new to client side framework. Please help

Comment: the problem is, you change the purpose of the question **and** you did not include some code, you tried.

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz added the tried code and expected result. Please help

Comment: I am actively looking into this